# Email Alert Related Contact

Tags: email, contact, email-alert

Can I define to which email adress the email gets sent if I choose the related contact in the email alert?
What email field of the related contact will the system choose ?

Unfortunately I cannot test it in our staging environment because we disabled all email and before we go live I would like to have some idea. And i cannot find any documentation. Would be very happy about some help.

[image]

Comment: The Related Contact is typically the `Case.Contact` field but would also apply to other standard objects that have an OOTB Contact relationship

Comment: @cropredy Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard field: **Email** of Contact object is referenced to trigger email in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you very much!